# Error Number: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1242

I have a table called view_att_tabulation which holds the daily attendance info of an employee for a given day & tbl_employ holds all the information about an employee. I want to retrieve the attendance of all the employees who are active=Y, whose status is 1, and whose employee_id starts with "W" on a given date. The below code always works fine for today and yesterday but always throws an error for dates before that. Any suggestion on where I have gone wrong?

```
SELECT emp_id, employ_id, employ_label, employ_name, employ_shortname, status, active_flag,
    (SELECT
        CASE
        WHEN (
            SELECT view_att_tabulation.emp_id FROM view_att_tabulation 
            WHERE view_att_tabulation.emp_id = tbl_employ.emp_id AND 
            employ_workdate = '2024-01-17' AND attendance_type LIKE 'PRESENT'
        )
        THEN 'PRESENT'
        WHEN
        (
            SELECT view_att_tabulation.emp_id FROM view_att_tabulation 
            WHERE view_att_tabulation.emp_id = tbl_employ.emp_id AND 
            employ_workdate ='2024-01-17' AND attendance_type LIKE 'ABSENT'
        )
        THEN 'ABSENT'
        ELSE ''
    END
   )AS employ_att
FROM tbl_employ
WHERE  active_flag = 'Y' AND status = '1' AND employ_id LIKE 'W%'
ORDER BY employ_att, `tbl_employ`.`employ_id` ASC;
```

Comment: instead of this lengthy query. direct go for 2 table join and get all data accordingly. this `PRESENT` and `ABSENT` you can do in view. It will make query more clear and run faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT 
    tbl_employ.emp_id,
    tbl_employ.employ_id,
    tbl_employ.employ_label,
    tbl_employ.employ_name,
    tbl_employ.employ_shortname,
    tbl_employ.status,
    tbl_employ.active_flag,
    CASE
        WHEN view_att_tabulation.attendance_type = 'PRESENT' THEN 'PRESENT'
        WHEN view_att_tabulation.attendance_type = 'ABSENT' THEN 'ABSENT'
        ELSE ''
    END AS employ_att
FROM 
    tbl_employ
LEFT JOIN 
    view_att_tabulation ON tbl_employ.emp_id = view_att_tabulation.emp_id
        AND view_att_tabulation.employ_workdate = '2024-01-17'
WHERE  
    tbl_employ.active_flag = 'Y' 
    AND tbl_employ.status = '1' 
    AND tbl_employ.employ_id LIKE 'W%'
ORDER BY 
    employ_att, tbl_employ.employ_id ASC;
```

replaced the subqueries with a `LEFT JOIN` on `view_att_tabulation` based on the `emp_id` and `employ_workdate`. Then, I've used a `CASE` statement directly in the main query to determine the `employ_att` value based on the `attendance_type`.

This should simplify your query and might help resolve the issue you're facing with dates before today or yesterday. Make sure to adapt the date condition in the `WHERE` clause and the `view_att_tabulation.employ_workdate` comparison based on your needs.